# UIButton is not appear on view in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, ios9

I have created my project in iOS 8 it works fine and now i am trying to run in iOS9.UIButton is not appearing. I have created a button programmatically, but it is not appearing only in iOS9. It works fine in iOS7 and iOS8. Please see the below code.

```
    UIButton *NewOrderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [NewOrderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [NewOrderButton setTitle:@"Create" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NewOrderButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-200)/2,(self.view.frame.size.height+80)/2, 200, 40.0);
    [NewOrderButton.layer setBorderWidth:1];
    [NewOrderButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    NewOrderButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton];
```

If i debug this code, then the button is appearing.

Comment: where did you add this code on your viewcontroller? in viewDidLoad method?

Comment: is not `_NewOrderButton` it is `NewOrderButton`

Comment: Sorry. Please check i edited my question

Comment: @Cong Tran I have added in viewDidAppear

Comment: pls check my answer. Hope it help.

Comment: try after adding `[self.view  layoutIfNeeded]` after `[self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton]`

Comment: Do you use storyboard or xib?

Comment: @ user3182143  yes, i am using storyboard

Comment: Let me know my answer is whether working or not.

Comment: @ user3182143  If i add that code in new project its working fine. But not with my current project. I am calling register function in viewDidAppear. In register func, i am using my code.

Comment: current project means?

Comment: @ user3182143 Please see my question I have created my project in xcode 6.4 and iOS SDK 8.4 Its working in iOS 7,8 in real device and simulator as well, but not in iOS9.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96258/discussion-between-user3182143-and-elavarasan).

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in my environment. just change following

```
[self.view addSubview:_NewOrderButton];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton];
```

Comment: Did you checked in iPad

Comment: I checked your code in iPad , none of problem I faced, your code is perfectly correct

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik  I have created my project in iOS 8 it works fine and now i am trying to run in iOS9.UIButton is not appearing

Comment: @elavarasan -- I checked in iOS 9 and above on my iPad air, it comes in center on VC, if you have a doubt set the background color of your button and check once bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik  please ckeck the below link  same problem i am facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976447/ios-9-view-not-appearing

Answer (score 0):

i ran it in iOS 9 it works fine..

and change the last line of your code with these..

```
[self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton];
```

i hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code to

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIButton *NewOrderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [NewOrderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [NewOrderButton setTitle:@"Create" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NewOrderButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-200)/2,(self.view.frame.size.height+80)/2, 200, 40.0);
    [NewOrderButton.layer setBorderWidth:1];
    [NewOrderButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
    NewOrderButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    [self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elavarasan I applied  your coding in viedDidLoad and viewDidLayoutSubviews,it works fine.Also please set the background color for the button.Below is the code.Again apply this code in your class.Definitely you will get solution.

```
UIButton *NewOrderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[NewOrderButton addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[NewOrderButton setTitle:@"Create" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
NewOrderButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
NewOrderButton.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/250)/2,(self.view.frame.size.height+80)/2, 200, 40.0);
[NewOrderButton.layer setBorderWidth:1];
[NewOrderButton.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]];
NewOrderButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:NewOrderButton];
```